# Creating gores for globe?

Tags: globe

I'm trying to convert an equirectangular map into a sinusoidal interrupted projection (with 10 or 20 degree gores) with the intention of making a globe with the gores once printed out. However, I'm running into a problem with the lines of latitude - sinusoidal projection projects the latitudes as parallels, however this results in lines of latitude that are geometric rather than circular, particularly close to the poles (I hope I'm making sense).

Is there another projection, similar to sinusoidal interrupted that distorts the lines of latitude in such a way that when printed and attached to a globe would result in circular lines of latitude, as desired? And if so, how can I (easily) go about changing an equirectangular map into such a suitable projection?

(NB: as though my questions werent a giveaway as it was, I'm in no way a professional when it comes to GIS! I'm using photoshop to create the equirectangular map and G. Projector to convert it into Sinusoidal interrupted projection, and that's about the extent of my knowledge! Also, the map is not of earth so I can't just find one and use that (though I might be able to take a blank set of such gores and convert my existing map to it)

Comment: Have you searched the site for other questions on gores? There are also some discussions on [Cartotalk](http://www.cartotalk.com).

Answer (score 0):

I may be 5 years too late, but you can use this website: https://www.winski.net/globus-projector/globus.html